# Sidekiq jobs giving error on cloud66 but working fine on my local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob, cloud66

I am setting up `sidekiq` with active job on `cloud66`. I schedule jobs and that are working fine on my local but giving error on `cloud66`.

I have also placed exception handling and I don't see coding error.

**Error:**

> TID-19444p SendingRemindersJob JID-e5ec7d67a0d89f09cb28d8e2 INFO:
>   start sidekiq.log — 11965 TID-19444p SendingRemindersJob
>   JID-e5ec7d67a0d89f09cb28d8e2 INFO: fail: 0.007 sec sidekiq.log — 11965
>   TID-19444p WARN: {"context":"Job raised
>   exception","job":{"class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"SendingRemindersJob","queue":"reminders","args":[{"job_class":"SendingRemindersJob","job_id":"a8493a7c-b05d-42c0-abf1-ea4b2079346a","provider_job_id":null,"queue_name":"reminders","priority":null,"arguments":[[1],"1",1,"2019-01-31
>   06:09:01
>   UTC"],"executions":0,"locale":"en"}],"retry":true,"jid":"e5ec7d67a0d89f09cb28d8e2","created_at":1548914857.7527065,"enqueued_at":1548915600.3969836,"error_message":"uninitialized
>   constant
>   SendingRemindersJob","error_class":"NameError","failed_at":1548914941.2146854,"retry_count":4,"retried_at":1548915278.9804192},"jobstr":"{\"class\":\"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper\",\"wrapped\":\"SendingRemindersJob\",\"queue\":\"reminders\",\"args\":[{\"job_class\":\"SendingRemindersJob\",\"job_id\":\"a8493a7c-b05d-42c0-abf1-ea4b2079346a\",\"provider_job_id\":null,\"queue_name\":\"reminders\",\"priority\":null,\"arguments\":[[1],\"1\",1,\"2019-01-31
>   06:09:01
>   UTC\"],\"executions\":0,\"locale\":\"en\"}],\"retry\":true,\"jid\":\"e5ec7d67a0d89f09cb28d8e2\",\"created_at\":1548914857.7527065,\"enqueued_at\":1548915600.3969836,\"error_message\":\"uninitialized
>   constant
>   SendingRemindersJob\",\"error_class\":\"NameError\",\"failed_at\":1548914941.2146854,\"retry_count\":4,\"retried_at\":1548915278.9804192}"} sidekiq.log — 11965 TID-19444p
>
> WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant SendingRemindersJob

So, Please help me to solve this and make it work smoothly as my local. Thanks.

Comment: Can you load `SendingRemindersJob` class and execute this job from rails console?

Comment: Yes as I have mentioned before working fine on my local also working fine with .perform() method

Comment: Can you load SendingRemindersJob class and execute this job from rails console on cloud66?

Comment: *Yes I can like:*  SendingRemindersJob.set(wait_until: Time.now+10.seconds).perform_later([1], "1", 1, "2019-01-31 06:09:01 UTC")   *and it gives*:  Enqueued SendingRemindersJob (Job ID: a27e8f59-bb4e-45e4-9782-f34bf08b1a34) to Sidekiq(reminders) at 2019-01-31 07:38:11 UTC with arguments: [1], "1", 1, "2019-01-31 06:09:01 UTC"